# Change TreeViewItem Header by trigger

Tags: wpf, header, treeviewitem

Having such Style

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="Pink"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I would expect the text of the expanded TreeViewItems to be "Pink", but nothing set actually. If I change to Property="Background" instead, it works. How *Header* differs from *Background*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'll need more info to answer this more completely.  However, if I have to guess, I'd say you're probably setting the Header property on the TreeViewItem explicitly like this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem
        Header="Blue"/>
</TreeView>
```

And, in this case, setting it explicitly will override anything that you put in the style.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on ascalonx's answer:

copied from [Josh Smith's](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/05/16/demystifying-dependency-properties/) blog:

> There is a well-defined set of rules
>   which is used internally by WPF to
>   figure out what the real value of a DP
>   is.  Here is a brief summary of the
>   rules of precedence used when
>   resolving the value of a DP (from
>   highest to lowest priority):
>
> 1. Property system coercion
> 2. Active animations, or animations
>      with a Hold behavior
> 3. Local value
> 4. TemplatedParent template
> 5. Style triggers
> 6. Template triggers
> 7. Style setters
> 8. Theme style
> 9. Inheritance
> 10. Default value from dependency
>        property metadata

So if you explicitly set the Header property, (or if you bind it I think), you have that problem.